# PyQt5 Segmentation fault (Core dumped)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 with Python 3.5. When I try to import `from PyQt5 import QtGui` `Segmentation fault` arise. Why it is happening?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Before the importation worked and just happen that? Or have you recently installed pyqt5?

Comment: Earlier I worked with PyQt4. Just updated to PyQt5.

Comment: PyQt5 and PyQt4 are 2 different packages, pyqt5 is not the update of pyqt4, how have you installed pyqt5?

Comment: Using ``conda install``

Comment: This package https://anaconda.org/dsdale24/pyqt5?

Comment: No this package : https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt

Comment: It seems that it has a bug, I recommend you report it to conda, I would recommend installing pyqt5 with `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`,

Answer (score 0):

Same error when I use anaconda PyQt5

I installed PyQt5 by

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```

result:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import *
>>> from PyQt5.QtGui import *
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

solved by:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

result:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import *
>>> from PyQt5.QtGui import *
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
>>>
```